# Including confidentiality information in Sphinx reST

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have the confidentiality text in its own "copy.rst" document. How can I include it without it showing up in the toctree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add copy.rst to a separate toctree with the `:hidden:` option:

```
.. toctree::

   doc1.rst 
   doc2.rst

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   copy.rst
```

You could also do nothing (just keep copy.rst with the other .rst files) and simply ignore the "copy.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree" message.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be

1. Do not include `copy.rst` in any `.. toctree:`.  This way this page will not come in next/previous.
2. Write `:orphan:` to the first line of `copy.rst`.  This way you will not see any compiler warning.